# What is the best way to fetch same data multiple times in a page?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to show the same data in a page where the data was fetched from MySQL multiple times.

First I want to get data from MySQL using `mysql_fetch_assoc()` in a while loop and then show it as a menu. The second time I want to show the same data as a sitemap in the footer.

I'm currently calling `mysql_fetch_assoc()` twice, as follows:

```php
// This one is the Menu
echo '<ul class="menu">';
while( $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) ) { 
    echo '<li><a href="page.php?id='.$data['id'].'">'.$data['title'].'</a>';
}
echo '</ul>';

// other page contents here

// at the footer - the small sitemap
echo '<ul class="sitemap">';
while( $f_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) ) { 
    echo '<li><a href="page.php?id='.$f_data['id'].'">'.$f_data['title'].'</a>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

I think the code above might be using more resources than needed by querying the database twice. Since I have the data in the page, to fetch the same data again is wasting memory and not good.

So my questions are:

1. Does it send separate queries and fetch data from the database each time I use `mysql_fetch_assoc()`? Or is it only fetching data from the database once, and later it just loops through an existing array?
2. What is the best solution in my case?

Simply - Am I doing this in the best way? Is there any better way to do this, by not wasting memory/resources/time? Since it's the same data I'm showing twice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your best solution would be to store your retrieved data in an array, which you can then use whenever you want without having to make more queries to your database, like so:

```
// First we make the query and store the rows in an array
$result = mysql_query($query);
$data_array = array();
while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data_array[] = $data;
}

// Then we can loop through the values in that array without making further queries
echo '<ul class="menu">';
foreach ($data_array as $data) {
    echo '<li><a href="page.php?id=', $data['id'], '">', $data['title'], '</a>';
}
echo '</ul>';

// Another loop through our array
echo '<ul class="sitemap">';
foreach ($data_array as $f_data) {
    echo '<li><a href="page.php?id=', $f_data['id'], '">', $f_data['title'], '</a>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 4):

Just make a reference to it :)

```
$menu = '<ul class="menu">';
while( $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) )
{ 
    $menu .= '<li><a href="page.php?id='.$data['id'].'">'.$data['title'].'</a>';
}
$menu .= '</ul>';

// header 
echo $menu;


// footer
echo $menu;
```

Comment: Just a note that the OP is looking to put a different class on each of the `<ul>` elements.  Easily achieved here using 2 variables `$menu` and `$sitemap` to start the list, and referring to its innards (the loop) as something like `$list`.  Then just `echo $menu . $list . "</ul>";`

Comment: Ah good catch. I'd actually just make a div wrapper. <div id="menu"><ul>....  and <div id="sitemap"><ul>... then the CSS can just be #sitemap ul and #menu ul

Comment: This one will work, but I think storing data into array is a better idea, so I can use them in more custom way.

Answer (score 3):

Save the fetched information into an array, and loop through this array for both the menu and the footer.

Answer (score 3):

1.No it does not. `mysql_query` queries the database and `mysql_fetch_assoc` is used to filter the resultset that is returned.

2.There is a simpler solution:

```
$output = "";
while( $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) )
    $output .= "<li><a href='page.php?id={$data['id']}'>{$data['title']}</a></li>";

echo "<ul class='menu'>{$output}</ul>"; // This one is the Menu
// other page contents here
echo "<ul class='sitemap'>{$output}</ul>"; // at the footer - the small sitemap
```

Comment: If it does not, will `mysql_fetch_assoc` still waste resources?

Answer (score 2):

Why are you making multiple db calls for the same data? That is a waste of resources. Just save the db data to an array and then output it where you like and however you like.

Try this:

```
  while( $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) )
    $menu[$data['id']] = $data['title'];

  // This one is the Menu
  echo '<ul class="menu">';

  foreach ($menu AS $id => $title)
    echo "<li><a href='page.php?id=$id'>$title</a></li>";

  echo '</ul>';

  // other page contents here

  // at the footer - the small sitemap
  echo '<ul class="sitemap">';

  foreach ($menu AS $id => $title)
    echo "<li><a href='page.php?id=$id'>$title</a></li>";

  echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Thats why I asked to be sure and know the better way to do it.
Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `mysql_data_seek($result, 0);`

It sets the pointer of the result set back to the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Use the mysqli_data_seek($result, 0).

Seems much more efficient and works like a charm